# Upgrading from android-19 to android-22 with appcompat-v7

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-design-library

I am upgrading my android app which compiles with `android-19` to `android-22`. With this change i would like to support material design and make it compatible with lower versions of Android. So i am going to use `appcompat-v7 22.2.1`.

I am developing in **Eclipse** and I have no way to find `appcompat-v7 22.2.1` library with resources. In my andorid-sdk directory i found `appcompat-v7 23.X.X`. I could only find .jar files for older appcompat-v7 but not library project including resources. Where can i find those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all please consider to switch to Android Studio.

You can find all the release of the app compat library in this folder:

```
sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7
```

Here you can check all version.
In the 22.2.1 folder you will find the `appcompat-v7-22.2.1.aar` file.
Inside you can check the `classes.jar` file,the res folder and the AndroidManifest file.

- Create a project in your workspace
- Unzip the AAR into some directory.
- Copy the `AndroidManifest.xml`, the `res`, and `assets` folders from the AAR into your project.
- Create a `libs` directory in your project and copy into it the `classes.jar`
- Add the dependency, in your case you have to add the support-v4.jar library.
- Use the SDK 22 to compile
- Mark the project as a library

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Using Android studio is not an option for me because of complicate c++ make files in my project. I cannot migrate until Android Studio supports that. 

I tried recreating library by using jar files and extracted assets from appcompat-v7-22.2.1.aar file but i was unable to create a library project out of it.

Can you may be explain a little more on how to go about using .aar file?

Comment: @Hakeem Just updated the answer with more details to extract the files from the aar to build the project with Eclipse.

Comment: Cool. I am gonna give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: It worked. I am able to compile appcompat-v7-22.2.1 & include it as lib to my app